# Publish blazor using localhost

Tags: blazor, share, publish

I'm sorry for my question, but I can't figure out of this theme.
I need to share blazor project, but my colleague haven't visual studio. For this I want to publish project.
And when I publish in folder and open exe file, open only console, not site on local host. What can I do? I think about docker, but I want to see opinion of users)

Comment: When the console opens it says something like `listening on http(s)://localhost:xxxx`. If you open that url in a browser, you can view the page.

Comment: Oh, I should have read what console write... Thanks

Comment: Ill post it as answer. When you accept that as answer we might help others as well :)

Comment: you can install IIS and host your blazor application there in few steps, install IIS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio deploy blazor app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the console opens it says something like `listening on http(s)://localhost:xxxx`. If you open that url in a browser, you can view the page.